# could not parse mapping document from resource

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I always get this error message when i call my servlet...

```
failed:org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource CarDetail.hbm.xml
```

CarDetail.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="at.opendata.entitys">      
    <class name="CarDetail" table="cardetail">
        <id name="id" column="detail_id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="gone" type="time"/>
        <property name="back" type="time"/>
        <property name="currentdatetime" type="timestamp"/>
        <property name="coordinates" type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType" column="coordinates"/>
        <many-to-one name="car" column="car_id" class="Car" not-null="true"/>       
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Why do i get this error message? Another mapping file is found in the same directory..

Comment: because you have invalid document

Comment: didn't put a type of id attribute

Comment: i miss an id? and where?

Comment: @krackmoe You don't miss an id. You miss the **type** of the id. Instead of `<id name="id" column="detail_id">` you need to specify `<id name="id" type="int" column="detail_id">`. Apparently, [the very nice tutorial on joss.org](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-setup) is buggy (like most tutorials on the web...)

Comment: Another example of a "tutorial bug" is that the [mapping file](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-mapping) specifies a `<class name="Event"` that isn't fully qualified, which leads to an ugly exception when trying to run the thing. Instead, it should be [a fully qualified class name (with package)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6692937/1864054).